# Azure Data Factory Storage events trigger "'InitializefolderPath ' is not valid" issues

Tags: azure-data-factory, eventtrigger

it triggered ADF pipeline sucessfully with correct @triggerBody().folderPath and @triggerBody().fileName, however the pipelines always fail in the beginning ( there is only a task "wait 1s" in the pipeline )

[image]

I have tried to short the trigger name to 'trigger1", redeploy the adf and issue persisted.

Comment: Hi, where are you defining 'InitializefolderPath '?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you are having space in the name.

1. Make sure you do not have any space in the names used in the trigger.
2. Make sure to publish any new changes made on the pipeline or trigger.
3. If the error still persists, try creating a new pipeline/trigger with new names without spaces at the end.

I have created a pipeline with wait activity as 1s as you mentioned and created a storage event trigger and successfully executed the trigger.